# How to tell what is entered in an input field in real time after clicking a button and != submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am thinking what is the best way to do what the title suggests? I am just learning JS/JQ and not sure what's the best method.

I have a button in a form to go to next  that doesn't work if certain input fields do not meet criteria. What is the best thing to do? Do I need to add constant listeners to those fields to update the value?

If you just point me in the right direction I will take it from there.

My current code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        if(selectedSlots.length < 2 ||
        $("#field1").length < 1 ||
        $("#field2").length < 1){
            var origMsg = $(this).get(0).parentNode.innerHTML;
            var errorMsg = "<p style=\"text-align:center;padding:0;margin:0;\">Please ";
                if(selectedSlots.length < 1)errorMsg += "select at least one availability slot";
                if($("#field1").length < 1){errorMsg += "enter the position you wish to apply for"};
                if($("#field2").length < 1){errorMsg += "enter the amount of hours you would like to work"};
                errorMsg += " before continuing.</p>";

            $(this).get(0).parentNode.innerHTML = origMsg + errorMsg;

            return;

        }
        $("#currentDiv").slideUp();
        $("#nextDiv").slideDown();

    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#field1").length` you are saying that the DOM element exists, has nothing to do with the text entered in it. I assume you want `$("#field1").val().length` and we have no clue what `selectedSlots` is

Comment: you question is not clear. Would you mind explain more ?

Comment: @epascarello $("#field1").val() returns undefined, with or without data in the input field. selectedSlots[] is irrelevant, it is a pre-built array.

Comment: @ths I just want to know how to read data entered by a user in #field1 and #field2 when the click event is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was missing is this little snippet after element `.get(0).value.` Thank you all for your time!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        if(selectedSlots.length < 2 ||
        $("#field1").length < 1 ||
        $("#field2").length < 1){
            var origMsg = $(this).get(0).parentNode.innerHTML;
            var errorMsg = "<p style=\"text-align:center;padding:0;margin:0;\">Please ";
                if(selectedSlots.length < 1)errorMsg += "select at least one availability slot";
                if($("#field1").get(0).value.length < 1){errorMsg += "enter the position you wish to apply for"};
                if($("#field2").get(0).value.length < 1){errorMsg += "enter the amount of hours you would like to work"};
                errorMsg += " before continuing.</p>";

            $(this).get(0).parentNode.innerHTML = origMsg + errorMsg;

            return;

        }
        $("#currentDiv").slideUp();
        $("#nextDiv").slideDown();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the onBlur event to validate and set errors on the input when the user click on any other place other than the submit button.